# Out of bounds 2D array error in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

Im stuck on this one part and I was hoping to get some help. I have a project that is basically a word search. The program reads in a file that contains the Rows and columns followed by the word search puzzle itself. You are required to create possible combinations of strings from the word search and  check those combinations with a dictionary that is provided as another text document.

Here's an example of the file read in 1st is Rows and 2nd is Cols followed by the word search puzzle:

```
4 4
syrt
gtrp
faaq
pmrc
```

So I have been able to get most of the code to work except for the function that creates strings for the above file. Basically It needs to search the wordsearch and create strings, each created string gets passed on to another function to check if it's in the dictionary. However my code keeps going out of bounds when creating the strings, and it's continuing to cause Seg faults which is really frustrating.

Theses are the constants that are declared, its every possible direction to go while searching the word search puzzle for possible string combinations

```
const int DX_SIZE = 8;
const int DX[] = {-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1};
const int DY[] = {-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1};
```

This is the function I have to create the strings:

```
int strCreate(char** puzzle, char** dictionary, int n, int rows, int col){

int x, y;
int nextX, nextY, i;
char str[20] = {0};
int length = 1;

for(x = 0; x < rows; x++)
  {

    for(y = 0; y < col; y++)
     {

        //Grabs the base letter
        str[0] = puzzle[x][y];
        length = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < DX_SIZE; i++)
         {

          while(length < MAX_WORD_SIZE)
          {

             nextX = x + DX[i]*length;
             nextY = y + DY[i]*length;


            // Checking bounds of next array
            //This is where I'm having trouble.

            if((x + nextX) < 0 || (nextX + x) > (col-1)){
                printf("Out of bounds\n");
                break;
            }

            if((y + nextY) < 0 || (nextY + y) > (rows-1)){
                printf("Out of bounds\n");
                break;
            }  

            str[length] = puzzle[nextX][nextY];


            //search for str in dictionary
            checkStr(str, dictionary, n);
            length++; 
            }
            memset(&str[1], '\0', 19);
         }
      }
   }
return 0;
}
```

I know i'm not checking the bounds properly I just can't figure out how to. When X = 1 and nextX = -1, that passes the bounds check, however say the array is at puzzle[0][0] nextX would put puzzle[-1][0] which is out of bounds causing the seg fault.

Thank you for taking the time to read, and I appreciate any help at all.

Comment: I think the arrary bound for DX and XY looks OK. Could you please add more details on how puzzle and str are defined?

Comment: Str is defined at the top of the function. Puzzle is declared using dynamic memory allocation by using the rows and the columns from the file that is read in.

Comment: @Kris Please don't remove the code from the question. It makes the answer look completely out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nextX and nextY are the indices used to access the array puzzle. Then the array bound check should also include the same. But the array bound check includes for example x+nextX.

```
        // Checking bounds of next array
        //This is where I'm having trouble.

        if((x + nextX) < 0 || (nextX + x) > (col-1)){
            printf("Out of bounds\n");
            break;
        }
```

Example:
           if( nextX < 0)
              printf("Out of bounds...\n");

Comment: This fixed the out of bounds error! Thank you! Now that its running, I come to find that its not creating the strings correctly ><

Comment: Why is `int length = 1;` and not `0`?